# Github and SVN Workflow

Tags: svn, git, github

I'm working on a project with 2 more developers. The problem is that 1 developer is using SVN and the other developer and I using github. Is there a way to keep everything synced on both sides SVN and git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either force the other guy to use `git`, or have the `svn` repository be the main one, and use [`git-svn`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-svn.html) to pull/push from/to it.

Answer (score 12):

When I had to deal with this one time, I just told the other guy to learn git and suck it. Eventually, he did and everyone was happy. I suggest that :-)

Answer (score 1):

`git` is more flexible and powerful and might be a better option than using both types of version control systems in parallel. The `svn` user can be taught to use `git` now to save more headaches later.

Answer (score 0):

[As of April 2010 GitHub provides a (readonly) interface to svn](https://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support). If he insists to use svn and to not learn git, he should send patches and one of the git users (or automated) checks them into a separate branch for that developer.